# How can I set the vertical alignment in Pandoc's beamer columns?

Tags: pandoc, beamer

The following code is adapted from [the official documentation](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#columns):

```
:::::::::::::: {.columns align=center}
::: {.column width="40%"}
contents...
:::
::: {.column width="60%"}
contents...

more content
:::
::::::::::::::
```

I would expect both columns to center vertically.

When running `pandoc document.md -t beamer`, this outputs (among other things) the line `\begin{columns}[T]`, which aligns the columns at the top, instead of outputting `\begin{columns}[c]` or just `\begin{columns}`.

[I've tried looking at the code already](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/eb4fe697f0594d28209361db4a93e9d539a1acdf/src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/LaTeX.hs#L1047), but my Haskell and my understanding of pandoc's interna is too bad to understand it.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this just a bug? Is `align=center` supposed to do what I think it should?

Comment: works for me in pandoc 2.10.1 – it outputs `\begin{columns}[c]
\begin{column}{0.4\textwidth`

Comment: I can reproduce the problem with rstudio cloud (no idea which pandoc version is used there)

Comment: I think this feature was added in a later pandoc version then rstudio is using...

Comment: Heh, it looks like this is a brand-new feature in Pandoc: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/tag/2.10 ([here's the PR](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/pull/6331)) - I happened to read the documentation on the website, which is already updated, but did not have the newest version locally. Thanks guys!

Comment: By the way, can I somehow mark my question as answered? Do I have to copy my answer into an actual answer post to do so?

Comment: "Do I have to copy my answer into an actual answer post to do so?" jep, that's how it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commenters under my question gave me the decisive hint: I was simply using an old version of Pandoc. In fact, the feature is brand-new: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/tag/2.10 ([here's the PR](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/pull/6331))

I happened to read the documentation on the website, which is already updated, but did not have the newest version locally.